# Why does a manually reused UITableViewCell disappear on row-reload?

Tags: uitableview, reuseidentifier

If I keep a fixed `UITableViewCell` with reuseidentifier=`nil` as an ivar and return this instance for a specific row, and then reload this row specifically using `[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:]`, the row contents disappear (or sometimes flicker). When I scroll away and back, it becomes visible again. If I do `[tableView reloadData]` on the other hand, it will not disappear.

- Why does it disappear, when I reload the row ?
- Why doesn't it, when I reload the whole table ?

Here is a sample project: https://github.com/hannesoid/HOTableViewTests

I tested this on iOS 6.
*I know that manually reusing a UITableViewCell in such a way (with out reuseidentifier & dequeueing) is not typically recommended, but in some quite static scenarios it would simplify things.*

Answer (score 1):

UITableView is optimized by Apple so that it uses a reasonably small amount of memory and yet still has good performance for when cells appear on the screen. When you do something non-standard like this, and circumvent the optimization, you throw the whole machine out of whack. Here's what I suggest. If you have one specific row that you're now holding as an instance variable, why not simply try giving it a unique name for its reuseIdentifier? Let the kit work it out.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good practice to make `reuseIdentifier` equal to `nil`. Always initialize `reuseIdentifier` with a string/name. The `cellForRowAtIndexPath` reloads rows by looking to their `reuseIdentifiers`. If cached cells are founds with an existing `reuseIdentifier`, it displays those cells directly without allocating and initializing new one. Making it `nil` causes problem. So, make `reuseidentifier=@"cell"` or something you like. This will solve your problem.